# How to paste floating point number from text file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, floating-point

I paste this text:

```
0.354
1.225
```

to Excel.

After pasting Excel interprets 0.354 as 0.354, but 1.225 as 1225.

How to make Excel interpret  1.225 as 1.225?

---

UPD0. I've found that Excel has somewhere two decimal digits as a default setting. If I type 1.17 (for example), then Excel interprets it as 1.17. If I type 1.117 (for example), then Excel interprets it as 1117. Totally unexpected. How to fix that?

Comment: Most likely your operating system region settings are set to have `.` as a thousands separator rather than as a decimal point.

Comment: Where can I find the "thousands separator" setting? I am on Windows 10.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989

Comment: @Mokubai Already did. I don't see any "thousands separator" setting.

Comment: Looks like you need the "old style" region settings https://resrequest.helpspot.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=279 and you want these https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGTAr.png

Comment: (only comments at the moment because while I think these are what you want I'm not 100% certain that Excel honours them under all circumstances)

Comment: @pmor It is called "Digit grouping symbol" instead of "thousands separator".

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks! Now Excel displays 1.376 as 1. How to fix that?

Comment: @pmor Right-click the cell (or selection of cells) and choose "Format Cells...". Make an appropriate choice from the dialog which appears.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've manually formatted the cells to use 3 decimal places. How to globally set the number of decimal places to N?

Comment: @pmor [How to change the default number format in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44680465/1115360)

Comment: Put a `'` at the start of the cell?